Filter activity: exclude data based on values from array
I am trying to prevent running pipelines that have dependency on previous pipelines (running with metadata). From filter activity I would get those failed ones. In the data that is passed on I have Dependency item. Basically if dependent pipeline failed I would like to filter out the data to not run what should not be ran.
Example:
Filter Activity (Get Failures) output
{
"ItemsCount": 1,
"FilteredItemsCount": 1,
"Value": [
    {
        "PipelineName": "PL_Main_1",
        "LastRunStatus": "F"
    }
]}

Metadata:
{
"count": 3,
"value": [
    {
        "pipelinename": "PL_Dep_1",
        "dependancy": "PL_Main_1"
    },
    {
        "pipelinename": "PL_Dep_2",
        "dependancy": "PL_Main_2"
    },
    {
        "pipelinename": "PL_Dep_3",
        "dependancy": null
    }]}

Based on this small example, filter activity should exclude PL_Dep_1. Of course, filter activity might have more then just one failure, maybe PL_Main_2 failed also, so only PL_Dep_3 should run since it does not have dependency.
I am not really sure what kind of expression in Filter activity I should use to do this.
I have this, but not working:
not(contains(item().Dependency, activity('GetFailures').output.value[0]['PipelineName'])) 


I did found what my issues was. I wasn't looking into null values. So to be able to solve my problem, below function was used:
if(
    equals(item().dependancy,null),
    true,
     not(contains(activity('GetFailures').output.Value[0].PipelineName,item().dependancy
)))

